# Как адаптивно делать такие блоки?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такую линию я знаю, но каким образом сделать это адаптивно при том, условии, что эти блоки будут складываться друг под друга.

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки решить задачу, добавьте [mcve], что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Находишь сайт где это уже реализовано и воруешь от туда. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

На пространство имён не обращай внимание

**Эта моя версия как расположить эту линию**

[codepen.io/topicstarter/](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/deXYGR?editors=1000)  *для проверки работы*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

items,
item {
  display: block;
}

items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

item-content {
  font-size: .8em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.item1:before,
.item2:before,
.item3:before,
.item4:before,
.item5:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: inherit;
  }
  item {
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
  }
  .item1:before,
  .item2:before,
  .item3:before,
  .item4:before,
  .item5:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .item1:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .item4:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .item5:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <items>
    <item class="item1">
      <item-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet .</p>
      </item-content>
    </item>
    <item class="item2">
      <item-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
      </item-content>
    </item>
    <item class="item3">
      <item-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consec</p>
      </item-content>
    </item>
    <item class="item4">
      <item-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </item-content>
    </item>
    <item class="item5">
      <item-content>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
      </item-content>
    </item>
  </items>
</wrapper>
```

Comment: Только after нужно высоту просто 100% задать, а то они вылезать начинают)

Comment: ааа .. это так задумано у меня было